# Proving the existence of a condition for reciprocal of derivatives of a given function

Tags: functions, derivatives, proof-writing

Let f be any continuously differentiable function on [a,b] and twice differentiable on (a,b) such that f(a)=a and f(b)=b. Then prove that there exists some distinct $c,d$ such that $$1/f'(c)+1/f'(d)=2$$I tried solving it using Rolle's theorem, Lagrange mean value theorem but got no way to reach any closer to the solution. It is the introduction of reciprocals of derivatives in the condition to be proved that stumps me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!